# Laravel multiple update slow

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a laravel 5.6 app that list items on the page, and at the same time collects views. The page averagely took 8 seconds to generated.

Table item

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
views INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Table items_daily_views

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items_daily_views (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
item_id INT NOT NULL,
date DATE NOT NULL,
views INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Model Item

```
class Item extends Model{
  protected $table='items';
}
```

Model ItemDailyViews

```
class ItemDailyViews extends Model{
  protected $table='items_daily_views';
}
```

HomeController.php

```
$itemList = Item::orderBy('id','desc')->take(100)->get();
foreach($itemList as $item){
   //increment to items
   $each=Item::find($item->id);
   $each->increment('views');

   //increment to items_daily_views
   $each=ItemDailyViews::updateOrCreate(
       ['item_id'=>$item->id,
        'date'=>Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')]
   );
   $each->increment('views');
}

return view('home',['itemList',$itemList]);
```

This page has around 200 update queries, and took 8 seconds to be generated. The former version of this app use pure PHP without laravel, and use around 10 milliseconds to generate (also significantly less RAM). I must do something wrong. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to do this `$each=Item::find($item->id);` inside your foreach since `$item` is already an instance of your Item model.

Answer (score 1):

## IDEA

May be instead of do it in laravel-eloquent, try to send raw SQL query using `DB::statement("UPDATE ...")` which update all viewed rows at once inside DB (below sql I write from head - test it (can contains bugs)):

```
UPDATE items
    SET views = views + 1
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 100;
```

You can use `WHERE` clausule to select proper rows that you wanna update. And use similar mechanism for table `items_daily_views` (it is a little bit more complicated because first you should check that proper row of given day exists ([create if not](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/25/insert-if-not-exists-queries-in-mysql/)), and then  update its view counter). In this technique you should be able to avoid send more than ~200 sql separate queries to DB from php (and send only few queries).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$itemList = Item::orderBy('id','desc')->take(100)->get();
foreach($itemList as &$item){ // pass by reference since you are modifying within foreach
   //increment to items
   $item->increment('views');

   //increment to items_daily_views
   $dailyViews = ItemDailyViews::firstOrCreate(
       ['item_id'=>$item->id,
        'date'=>Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')]
   );
   $dailyViews->increment('views');
}

return view('home',['itemList',$itemList]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$itemList = Item::orderBy('id','desc')->take(100)->get();
$itemDailyViews=[];
foreach($itemList as $item){
   //increment to items
   $item->itemDailyViews->date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
   $item->itemDailyViews->increment('views');
   array_push($itemDailyViews,$item->itemDailyViews);

}
$itemList->itemDailyViews()->saveMany($itemDailyViews);
return view('home',['itemList',$itemList]);
```

This will work if you have given the proper eloquent relationships.